# What to do with questions answered on other SE sites like DIY

Tags: discussion, diy

I was about to ask a question about resin rings under paint when I found the same question answered on DIY.SE

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11901/what-is-causing-caused-these-brown-circular-stains-in-my-cabinetry

If it has an answer is it pointless to ask again here on WW? This already happened to me once with a boiled linseed oil question. I think the question is a better fit for here anyway. Cross posting sucks but that is content that should exist here.

Answer (score 3):

Back when Woodworking.SE was going through Area51, the Community Team noted the potential for overlap with DIY. We decided the overlap wouldn't be too big of a problem because we believed woodworking could stand on its own as a discipline. What you have here, on this site, is a group of people who are familiar with the minutiae of woodworking in a way that folks on DIY may not be. As such, you have the opportunity to get much more in depth with your Q&A.

If you have a question which has already been asked and answered on DIY, but you can provide a much higher level of detail, by all means, ask it here. Stack Exchange sites are at their best when they're surfacing the details which reveal the cause and effect of a problem, and details help with this. Alternately, if a question has been asked already on DIY, and you're not able to provide more information when you ask it here, then its probably best to hold off.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, cross-posting is primarily frowned upon if the questions are asked by the same person at the same time.

This question in particular is a great fit for our site, so if you were naturally wondering the same thing, I see no problem with writing it up here, using own words and examples.  I would then wait to see if our own community of woodworking experts provide their own method.

Copying the question verbatim and making it community wiki seems like trying to hack a question migration. I've never seen it done like that and would prefer the question be presented here with original content.

Comment: I might have misworded my intentions but I do want to ask again _in my own words_. I, like you said, would like to see if our community has a different approach/ideas